# RabbitMq - Publish less when consumer is connected

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a quick question of understanding:
When I publish to a queue that has a consumer connected to it, why does the incoming rate break?

In the following screenshot you see on the left (yellow line) once a publish of 10k items with no consumer and directly after the same publish of 10000 items when a consumer is connected (green line). As you can see less can be published than without consumer

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuV29.png)

Thank you for your support!

Comment: A lot depends on how fast your consumer is acknowledging messages.

Comment: I know but that was not the question. The question was why the **Publish** collapses as soon as a consumer hangs on the queue.

Comment: I know nothing about your environment, or how you're running your test, yet you want me to guess at the cause. RabbitMQ must do more work when consumers are connected. If you want more information, you will have to provide a means to reproduce your test.